# What is the + at the end of Unix permissions in a long listing format?

Tags: unix, sudo, file-permissions, ls

Here's an example

```
drwxr-xr-x+  6 reza reza        204 Mar  5 20:23 .ssh/
```

Although I am the owner of this directory, I cannot modify it without using **sudo**!

Why is that? how can I remove '+' here (assuming that is the problem)?

Comment: In the future, **please don't cross-post** across multiple Stack Exchange sites. Thank you!

Comment: If it's a MacOS question, please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `+` is an indicator that there is an extended file ACL applied to that file.

On Linux you want [getfacl(1)](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/getfacl1.html) to read that, and my guess is that the ACL is what blocks your access to modify the directory.

On MacOS you want [chmod(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html), which has an extended command-line language to get and set ACL entries on files.

Comment: You're right that it's related to ACL. But i'm running Mac OS X 10.6 and getfacl or setfacl are not available (as well as chmod -N)...

Comment: I completely didn't consider the platform; added those details to the comment, but chmod `readsecurity` and `writesecurity` are the tools instead.

Comment: actually the `-N` in `chmod` is invisible to all users (including sudoers for the exception of 'root' user...
Thanks for the help though

Comment: The plus stands for ACLs as noted above, but you may need to use chattr as well.